# numpy get values in col2 given an array of values matching col1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I extract values in Col1 whose Col0 matches any values in a numpy array.
I have an np array A, idx.
Get me all values in Col1 of array A, whose Col0 values are 1 or 4.

```
A = np.array([[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13], [4,14]])

idx = [1, 4]
```

I can get for 1 value like this.. but I don't know to get for an array of idx.

```
vals = A[np.where(A[:,0]==4),1]
vals = A[np.where(A[:,0]==4),4]
```

a) how can I get the values of Col1 in A where Col0 values are 1 or 4 ( matching idx).

expected result = [11,14]

b) how can I get values of Col1 in A where row indices are 1,4 (matching idx)

expected result = [12, 14]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st part:

```
idx = [1, 4]
A[np.isin(A[:,0], idx), 1]
```

---

```
array([11, 14])
```

---

2nd part:

```
idx = [1, 3]
A[idx,1]
```

---

```
array([12, 14])
```

Comment: For the part2 I figured A[idx][:,1] would work. Thanks @Pygirl]

Comment: @py_newbie You have given wrong index. for 2nd part.